# Number Format with PHP to MySQL stored data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my inventory page (Im a nooby in PHP) I  have uploaded all my inventory items but the price column in MySQL its a VARCHAR 255 I want to format with php all the data in the price column to number format
I want this>> 10000 look like this>> 10,000

I actually have my code like this

```
 <div class='wrap'><b>Price</b><br>
     <div class='price'>$ $row[8]<br>
  </div>
```

Comment: `number_format()`? But I would suggest changing the column in your database. This will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I allready tried to change the column from VARCHAR to DECIMAL (it only contains numbers) but I cant  pops an errror dialog  "#1366 - Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1"

Comment: Ryan Vincent, no I´m not converting anything I´m just printing it :/ I know thats not the good way but its my first php site so im having some issues
How can i edit it?

Comment: Ok i have changed the colum from VARCHAR to INT but it still showing without a number format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...?

```
<div class="wrap"><b>Price</b></div>
    <div class="price">$ <?php echo number_format( $row[8] ); ?></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

If you're `echo`ing it, probably...

```
<?php
$formatted = number_format( $row[8] );
echo "<div class=\"wrap\"><b>Price</b></div>
        <div class=\"price\">$ {$formatted}</div>
        <br />
      </div>";
?>
```

Comment: Or even better: `money_format()`? http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php

Comment: I have tried 
echo number_format( $row[8] );
But it prints thw whole sentence, something like this:
number_format100000

Comment: That's why I added the `<?php ?>` part. PHP **has to be executed** inside those tags.

Comment: My bad!
<?php echo
<div class="wrap"><b>Price</b></div>
    <div class="price">$ number_format( $row[8] )</div>
    <br />
</div>
 ?>
I already have the php tags and the echo sentence but it still printing the "number_format"

Comment: So maybe that's the problem... try `<?php echo "<div class=\"wrap\"><b>Price</b></div><div class=\"price\">$ " . number_format( $row[8] ) . "</div><br />"; ?>`. The dot is the concatenation symbol for PHP strings.